# Force TMonthCalendar to display user defined date format

Tags: delphi, calendar, delphi-2009

By default `TMonthCalendar` shows date in the format that is set in Windows control panel (Short Date). I want to override this setting and force `TMonthCalendar` to always display my format regardless of Windows setting. Is it possible ?

Comment: Why? The user has selected the date format they're comfortable with on their machine. Leave it that way. If you need the date in your format for some reason, convert it afterward in your code. Forcing the user to enter or read dates that are in a format other than the one they prefer is not very considerate of the user (mine would be extremely irritated at me, and would make me very aware of it).

Comment: Because I write software just for me. It's only a hobby. I don't sell it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this control is a wrapper for the native [Month Calendar Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/month-calendar-control-reference). As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/month-calendar-controls#localization) states:

> The month-calendar control gets its format and all strings from
>   LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you can not change the date format settings of `TMonthCalendar`.

The reason for this is the fact that `TMonthCalendar` is actually just a wrapper around a calendar API from the OS. That is why not only is the date format in the form that is set in OS regional settings, but the whole look of the calendar matches the look of the OS on which you are running your application on.

So, I'm afraid you will have to look at some third party components for this. For instance, TMS Software has several calendar and date-time picking components as part of [`TPlannerCalendar`](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/plannercal.asp).